# Python: padding string according to *actual* length

Tags: python, string, tkinter, string-formatting

In python it is easy to pad a string with spaces according to number of characters. For example:

```
print "aaa".ljust(10) + "end"
print "www".ljust(10) + "end"
```

The output is:

```
aaa       end
www       end
```

Which looks great in here or in any other display where the size of all characters is equal. But when I output these two strings in a `Tkinter` program, they are not aligned because the characters 'a' and 'w' have different lengths in any Tkinter font.

How can I align strings in `Tkinter`?

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *

STANDARD_FONT = ("David",14)

TO = "TO"
SUBJECT = "SUBJECT"
DATE = "DATE"

content = [
    {TO:'Frye', SUBJECT:'Water Pipe Replacement Cost', DATE:'July 9'},
    {TO:'George', SUBJECT:'Fw: Cell phone reimbursement', DATE:'July 9'},
    {TO:'George, Tim', SUBJECT:'Travel', DATE:'July 10'},
    {TO:'Sandy, Jim', SUBJECT:'Fw: Welcome to WOW! - News', DATE:'July 10'},
    {TO:'Sandy, Jim', SUBJECT:'Re: Present from paulette', DATE:'July 10'},
    {TO:'George, Tim, Sandy, Jim', SUBJECT:'Voices Across Alaska: State Budget Priorities', DATE:'July 10'},
    {TO:'Frye', SUBJECT:'FW: Confirmation of the Novemberl 5th discussion', DATE:'July 10'},
    {TO:'Jim', SUBJECT:'Re: Happy Thanksgiving!', DATE:'July 11'}
]

def makeWindow () :
    global nameVar, phoneVar, select
    win = Tk()

    frame1 = Frame(win)
    frame1.pack()

    frame2 = Frame(win)       # Row of buttons
    frame2.pack()

    frame3 = Frame(win)       # select of names
    frame3.pack()
    scroll = Scrollbar(frame3, orient=VERTICAL)
    select = Listbox(frame3, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=17, width=100, font=STANDARD_FONT)
    scroll.config (command=select.yview)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    select.pack(side=LEFT,  fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    return win

def format_mail_str(mail):
    to = "To: " + mail[TO]
    subject = mail[SUBJECT]
    date = mail[DATE]
    spacing = " " * 5

    return to.ljust(40) + spacing + subject.ljust(30) + spacing + date.ljust(15)


def setSelect () :
    select.delete(0,END)
    for mail in content:
        select.insert (END, format_mail_str(mail))

win = makeWindow()
setSelect ()
win.mainloop()
```

I want the subject and the date to be aligned between all rows.

Comment: Aligning text in a GUI or a web browser usually means you just put the text in actual columns, and not rely on whitespace between the text to align anything.

Comment: In my specific case I'm using Tkinter, where it seems that every font has characters with different lengths

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I reworded my question. Please reopen it.

Comment: Most gui systems that I know of that can display fonts of a non-fixed-width, also have a means for telling you how long the string actually is (eg, in pixels).

Comment: Re-opened. Don't use spaces to align text. Use separate text labels instead.

Comment: How are you displaying those strings in Tkinter? In a multiline `Text` field, or in multiple stacked `Entry` widgets, or on a `Canvas`?

Comment: Also, note that you can use monospace fonts in Tkinter if that's required

Comment: @tobias_k I'm trying to align all lines in a Scrollbar

Comment: What do you mean, "in a Scrollbar"? You can't add text directly to a scrollbar, right? What kind of widget is the text actually contained in? Show some code!

Comment: please provide a bit more detail. Are you aligning text on a canvas? Strings in a text widget? Labels in a frame?  Text in a label?

Comment: @tobias_k, I added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows this code lines up "end" exactly:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
displaytext1 = "aaa".ljust(10) + "end"
displaytext2 = "www".ljust(10) + "end"
tkinter.Label(root, text=displaytext1, font = "Courier").pack()
tkinter.Label(root, text=displaytext2, font = "Courier").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Check the value of platform.system() and use other fixed-width fonts depending on the operating system.

Comment: Good answer, but you should emphasize the keyword "fixed-width font".

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to answer the question you asked, but I will propose a solution to your problem.
What you want are several columns.
There is a widget for that in tkinter, it is a treeview.

See for example:
http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

I usually recommand the

```
show='headings'
```

option in the Treeview constructor when you want a list (and not a tree).